# how to add checked items to a different array from unchecked items? angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to create a button that would delete all complete items in a to do list --- after trying several different ways to accomplish this, I figure its probably easiest to just send checked items to one array, and unchecked items to another array, so I can make a button that just clears the checked items array... but nothing I am doing is working... thoughts?

html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="To do..." ng-model="vm.myTask">
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.submitTask()">Submit</button>
<br>

<div ng-repeat="task in vm.myTasks" ng-class="'checkedbackground': task.checked">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{task.name}}" ng-model="task.checked">{{task.name}}
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.myTasks.splice($index, 1)">Delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="vm.clearAll()"> Clear Complete</button>
```

homeController.js

```
var myTasks = [];
var completeTasks [];

class HomeController {



//submit task from input value
submitTask(){
//push new task into array
  myTasks.push({name: this.myTask, checked: false});

}
constructor(myTask, checkedTask){
this.myTasks = myTasks;

}

clearAll(){



}

}



angular.module("myapp").controller("HomeController", HomeController);
```

I erased what I tried but some of what I tried involved this:

```
constructor(myTask, checkedTask){
    this.myTasks = myTasks;
    completeTasks.push({name: this.checkedTask, checked: true});
    }
```

that broke the whole thing though.

Comment: Can you read your question one more time? Because am unable to understand it. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Considering your original idea and the fact that you tagged this question with javascript**, what you can do is to create a deleter function, which goes through your original array (no need to create a separate one) , and then checks if the task has been completed (each list item can be a object with a property named 'isDone' ) , and if done, you can remove that item from array using `splice()`

Another way of doing this is

```
function clr() {
    var newlist = TaskList.filter(function (item,i,TaskArr) {
        if(item.check)
            return false;
        else return true;
    });
    TaskList = newlist;

}
```

This uses the `filter()` function to check if the item is checked (completed) and returns a new array which contains only uncompleted items.

Comment: i'm confused, you are talking about an if statement, then your if statement disappeared and the making a new array part...

Comment: My code was edited to make it smaller by Pankaj Parkar, see the answer history and you will find my code, maybe you'll understand that better.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan if you want original code, you can revert to older revision. just click on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44820957/1), I just had a thought about optimizing code

Comment: Thank you @PankajParkar , being new to StackOverflow, I didn't know that. ;

Comment: @karmadreamwalker you can view the original code now.